# Replace 4 digit in URL by text + 4 digit

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Using .htaccess, I need to replace the following URL:

```
www.domain.com/1234-text....
```

By:

```
www.domain.com/item/1234-text....
```

This is what I'm trying:

```
RewriteRule ^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-/(.*)$ https://www.domain.com/item/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I've been exploring the Regex wiki but couldn't find the right expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(\d{4}-.*)$ /item/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Ys it is not needed if same domain as the request.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4}\-.*)$ https://www.domain.com/item/$1 [R,L]
```